# Are class diagrams automatically updated? If not, is it possible to do this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, class-diagram, updating

Are class diagrams automatically updated?

If not, is it possible to do this, so new classes are automatically added and removed/renamed classes are removed from the class diagram? Maybe there's a plugin for this?

Comment: What type of sync/update u want? properties and mothods or adding classes to the diagram based on a certain condition/folder/namespace?

Comment: Why don't you test and find out?

Comment: @HarisHasan: Two reasons: too lazy and when I ask it here, people having the same question won't have to try it out.

Comment: @AhmedMagdy: Any changes to the classes (properties, methods, ...) but also adding classes and renaming classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the class diagrams in Visual Studio are kept in sync with the code. You can very easily verify this.

What's more, a class can appear in more than one diagram. All diagrams and the code are synced.

Comment: So if I rename a class, the diagram will be changed accordingly?

Comment: Yes. You can also rename the class in a Diagram. But only when using the Solution Explorer you can keep the filename in sync.

Comment: One thing to add - for me (VS2012) simply reopening the class diagram did not auto update it. I had to select 'View Class Diagram' again from the project's root and *then* my existing .cd file was updated.

Comment: In VS 2015 the existing diagram was not updated when I added new enums and classes. I had to drag&drop the new enums and classes to the opened window of class diagram and after that they appeared. 'View Class Diagram' option simply generated another new diagram, but didn't updated the existing one.